# updating pdf file in flutter app without update apk version

Tags: flutter, pdf

Hi I'm trying to put pdf file in my flutter app

put this pdf file need to update every 1 week

I used pdf assets but need to use pdf static URL

is there any web site could to upload my pdf with static URL.

I tried firebase but didn't understand it well.

please advice ..
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement functionality in the application that downloads the file from the cloud server (every week).

You can upload a new file (or replace) the file every week from your end. You can go with `FirebaseStorage`, `AWS S3 Bucket`, or any other storage provider.

I think `FirebaseStorage` will be more convenient as the official plugins are available, check the official docs thoroughly [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/overview/).